# Select and Show new Tab on control when values in txtbox change, but keep focus on txtbox

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, tabs, focus

I'm having this issue that should be pretty easy to solve but I just can't seem to figure it out or find an answer yet.  I have the following code:

```
Public Sub NotifyThatValuesChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    APIUserForm_MAIN.OnSecurityInputValuesChanged()
    APIUserForm_MAIN.MessageSender.TabControl.SelectTab(0)
End Sub
```

So, I'm rasing events when values within txtboxes change, and one of the things I want to do is change tab focus when these values change, which it is doing...but....I don't want the cursor (or focus) to change to the selected tab.  I want the cursor/focus to stay where it is at while this event happens, and for the tab selected on this other control to change from (1) to (0).

Thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's 100% possible.  Try putting the focus back into the textbox:

```
Public Sub NotifyThatValuesChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  APIUserForm_MAIN.OnSecurityInputValuesChanged()
  APIUserForm_MAIN.MessageSender.TabControl.SelectTab(0)
  TextBox1.Select()
End Sub
```

If multiple controls are calling *this* method, you can use the sender parameter:

```
DirectCast(sender, Control).Select()
```

Comment: That would be fine, but there are many txt boxes, plus a few buttons that I'm checking if things change with.  Is there a way to set focus to previous focus or something like that?

Comment: @AdamShip Updated to use the `sender` parameter.